# Problems with usb3 attached drive ERROR: Transfer event for disabled endpoint or incorrect stream ring

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, debian, external-hard-drive

I have a **HP Microserver gen8** that I'm using for testing and some minor backup.

This machine has a debian 9 installation, I'm planning to upgrade it to debian 12 when I will have some time, the machine isn't connected to internet anyways.

I bought a **Seagate ST8000DM004 8TB drive** to be used as external additional drive for backups of lesser importance that doesn't need raid redundancy.

I've put it in an **Orico USB3 external box**, formatted all the drive in GPT + one only partition EXT4 and attached to one of the usb3 ports of the machine.

In console I can see this error:

```
[2729.934652] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: ERROR Transfer event for disabled endpoint or incorrect stream ring
[2747.675287] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: @000000013c688ef0 00000000 00000000 1b000000 01078001
```

I wondered a bit and searched online, someone says that by **changing the usb cable things could have fixed** -> Nothing, I tried with various usb3 cables, changing the usb3 port on the machine, even changing the box (I have 3 copy of them and I use them under other os without issues).

**I tried copy things to and from the drive and everything works correctly, I did copy some 200 MB files around doing some md5 and sha256 comparison and they match perfectly.**

I also noticed that **under any of the usb2 ports the errors doesn't spills out** but that would mean use the drive at a very low speed that is very annoying.

**What can I risk, can I assume that the drive is SAFE to be used this way?**
Can errors appear later, would I have issues about filesystem corruption or the os is smart enough to see if there are problems in the transmitted data and resend the data in case?

TL;DR: do the usb3 act like TCP packets auto-checking if the data is sent correctly or there are any checks?

my fears:

- data transmitted can be transmitted corruptly once in a lifetime but maybe this can be prevented by making checksum copies like with rsync.
- **just attaching the drive via the usb3 port once can lead to filesystem degradation so I will have to format it and use it forever since the bare initial format always in usb2 ?**

btw the command that I use for mount the drive is a simple

```
mount /dev/sdf1 /mounthpath
```

Comment: You would need to test more to find the incompatibility : This enclosure+disk on another computer, another make of enclosure with this disk, this enclosure another make of of disk.

Comment: @harrymc I can't do it really, I have no other enclosures and no budget at the moment to buy other disks than this one. I would like to understand better the error in order to determine if is a problem in the long end or not. It only appears in the moment you attach and mount the drive, no further errors. So maybe its usable...

Comment: So what can anyone tell you then? If I google the issue I find similar examples, some suggesting correlation with ASMEDIA bridge chips, I can also find some Orico USB3 enclosures using this chip .. I can even find someone experiencing actual ext4 fs corruption. Is that the issue you're seeing? NO IDEA. Is there risk of data corruption? Always I'd say.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen maybe moving to debian12 would fix the issue I read of this errors in some topics of usb-dev team of the kernel. Debian 9 use an old kernel, maybe moving to 12 could be the fix?

Comment: It's definitely an obvious thing to try IMO.